# commerce kickstart - how to edit a view ? the link is missing

Tags: views, commerce

I am really clueless why the edit link of the view is gone in Drupal Commerce, even Drupal 6 used it before.

Where is the edit link?

Comment: I removed the confusing message you left to the developers of the distribution, and the unnecessary whinging. Please realise that this is a Q+A site and be sure to keep your questions focused. Thanks

Comment: You'll also want to update your question to give details about what edit link you're talking about. Currently it's near to incomprehensible

Comment: in druupal 6when you hover on page, near the top, the link appeared where you can click on it and edit the view, but now it is gone

Answer (score 0):

It is available if you enable the "Contextual Links" module.

[image: contextual links module]